# Jaccard Coefficient en predicción de enlaces

Tags: python

Estoy realizando un algoritmo de predicción de enlaces que prediga 100 enlaces ausentes de una red. Tengo una red de entrenamiento en formato gexf y un csv que contiene 85.000 posibles enlaces entre dos nodos del tipo:

```
Id
595-910
150-922
627-734
.
.
.
.
```

Había pensado en utilizar la métrica del Coeficiente de Jaccard para tener una estimación de los posibles enlaces, pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo para el total de posibles enlaces.

Mi código hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```py
    import numpy as np 
    import pandas as pd 
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    G=nx.read_gexf('/users_red_entrenamiento.gexf')
    print(nx.info(G))

   
 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
nx.draw(G,pos=nx.spring_layout(G),node_color='black',alpha=0.5,node_size=10,edge_color='orange',width=0.5)

edge_list=pd.DataFrame([ (e[0],e[1],e[2]['weight']) for e in G.edges(data=True)],columns=['user1','user2','weight12'])
    edge_list.head()
#Vecinos de un nodo al azar
    [ n for n in G.neighbors(str(26))]
#Peso del enlace entre dos nodos
    G.edges[['1','26']]['weight']
#Leer csv
    test=pd.read_csv(path+'/test.csv')
    test.head()
#Definir función Jaccard
    def jaccard_coefficient(G, ebunch=None):
        if ebunch is None:
            ebunch = nx.non_edges(G)
        def predict(u,v):
            chbors = list(nx.common_neighbors(G, u, v))
            union_size = len(set(G[u]) | set(G[v]))
            if union_size == 0:
                return 0
            else:
                return len(cnbors) /union_size
                
        return ((u, v, predict(u,v))for u, v in ebunch)
#Probando uso Jaccard
    preds = nx.jaccard_coefficient(G,[(105,709), (120,922)])
    for u, v, p in preds:
        '(%d, %d) -> %.8f' % (u, v, p)
```

Finalmente la salida que espero conseguir es el mismo csv añadiendo una columna con valores posibles True o False dependiendo de si el enlace entre cada par de nodos es posible o no del estilo:

```
     Id        Prediccion
    595-910     False
    150-922     False
    627-734     False
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Para ello tengo la salida preparada:

```py
test['Prediccion']=False
test.head()
#Sumatorio prediciones 
test.groupby('Prediccion').count()
#Escritura de datos a csv
test.to_csv('prediccion2.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: ¿Alguien puede arrojar algo de luz?